# Checking if point is inside a polygon which is a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.5

first what i get is an example

```
poly = [190, 50, 500, 310]
bbPath = mplPath.Path(np.array([[poly[0], poly[1]],
                 [poly[1], poly[2]],
                 [poly[2], poly[3]],
                 [poly[3], poly[0]]]))

bbPath.contains_point((200, 100))
```

the coordinate.csv file have two column,first column 'longitude 190 50 500 310',second column 'latitude 50 500 310 190 '

what i tried is

```
with open('coordinate.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in readCSV:
    print(row)
```

I do not know how to import csv data into the path and check if point is inside a polygon

Comment: Can you share your file 'coordinate.csv' or at least a portion of it please.

Comment: the coordinate.csv file have two column,first column 'longitude 190 50 500 310',second column 'latitude 50 500 310 190 '

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some simple manipulations to each row of your csv file:

```
from matplotlib import path as mplPath
import numpy as np

with open('coordinate.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        lon_list = row[0].split(' ') #split first column into words
        lat_list = row[1].split(' ') #split second column into words
        lonlat_zip = zip(lon_list[1:], lat_list[1:]) #zip lists together (skipping first word)
        lonlat_list = list(lonlat_zip) #create list
        lonlat_arr = np.array(lonlat_list) #create array
        bbPath = mplPath.Path(lonlat_arr) #create path
        result = bbPath.contains_point((200, 100))
        print(result)
```

I've broken the process down into small steps, which you can pull together.  Obviously, if the csv file is not exactly as described you will need to alter this to suit.